# Is there a (preferably native) Clojure binding to OrientDB, that supports the latest version of binary API?

Tags: clojure, connection, orientdb

Today I tried to find an OrientDB binding for Clojure. I have found 2 libs: https://github.com/eduardoejp/clj-orient and https://github.com/eduardoejp/orientdb.clj .

I have tried to connect using **clj-orient** first, but it just throws an Exception

```
OIOException Cannot connect to any configured remote nodes: 127.0.0.1:2424                  com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemote.createNetworkConnection (OStorageRemote.java:1413)
```

I have tried to connect through console, using the same credentials and connection was OK. It seems, that due to the fact of this lib is rather outdated, it tries to connect over outdated protocol. And it fails.

I did not tried **orientdb.clj**, cause it has no documentation at all. Maybe it is an option?

How clojure folks are connecting to the OrientDB nowadays?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 3):

If one of those libraries looks good to you in the terms of features implemented but a little bit out dated, then it makes sense to fork the library, upgrade what is missing and push it back to the open source community! :)

If you don't want to do that, then you can use OrientDB Java client in your Clojure code without problems.

*I'm NOT the author of any of these libraries.*

Answer (score 1):

Doing a [search of Clojars](https://clojars.org/search?q=orientdb) leads me to believe in 2021 your best option is [whoneedszzz/orientdb-client](https://clojars.org/whoneedszzz/orientdb-client)

Orient probably needs to update their [official docs](http://www.orientdb.com/docs/last/apis-and-drivers/) on this, which still recommend the old `eduardoejp` version.
(It looks like [someone else](https://github.com/7bridges-eu/clj-odbp) picked up support in 2017, but then dropped it again in 2019.)